# How can we set the background color in datatable through code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding my data in a datatable and then bind that datatable into a datagrid. I want that some rows of the datatable should be highlighted with some color. How can we do that from code-behind?

Comment: var Stack Overflow Wishlist += Support for tables in Editor.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your point of coloring the invoices and receipts

@RPM1984 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hook into the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) event of the **DataGrid**, in order to dynamically set the properties you desire.

On your HTML, set the *OnItemDataBound* attribue of the DataGrid to a server-side event.

```
<asp:DataGrid id="ItemsGrid" runat="server"
           ...
           OnItemDataBound="Item_Bound">
```

Then wire-up the server-side event handler:

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
{
  // some code to handle each bound item
}
```

You could then flip the colors based on the [ListItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype.aspx) enumeration:

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
   e.Item.BackColor = Color.Red;
else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   e.Item.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following code snippet to color the rows of the grid:

```
foreach (DataGridItem item in DataGrid1.Rows) {
    item.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

You can now place a condition in the `foreach` loop to just color the rows you want:

```
counter = 0;
foreach (DataGridItem item in DataGrid1.Rows) {
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
        item.BackColor = Color.Black;
    else
        item.BackColor = Color.Red;

    ++counter;
}
```

Or, as mentioned in RPM1984's answer, you could also attach yourself to the `OnItemDataBound` event, which is quite the better solution (depending on the situation), since you won't have to iterate through all the rows by hand:

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

Code-behind:

```
public void ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) {
        e.Item.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

**Regarding the coloring of the invoices and receipts**, you could use the following code snippet to achieve what you want, assuming that you're adapting the approach of using the `OnItemDataBound` event to update the row's `BackColor`:

Code-behind:

```
public void ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) {
        SalesPosition salesItem = e.Item.DataItem as SalesPosition;

        if(salesItem == null) return;

        if(salesItem.Type == SalesPositionType.Invoice)
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        else if(salesItem.Type == SalesPositionType.Receipt)
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add in your Tag ASP an event OnDatabound:

You need to TAG the event Datarow binding with this

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvAps" BackColor="Yellow" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridView_Entete" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" />
```

and in the code-behind specify action for the event:

```
 protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {   
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (drv["INVOICES/RECEIPTS "].ToString()) == "INVOICE" )

            {
            e.Row.Attributes.Remove("Class");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("Class", "GridView_New");
            }
  }
```

You can specify in the code a css class or simply modify the color of the row..

```
 protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {        
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (drv["INVOICES/RECEIPTS "].ToString()) == "INVOICE" )
                 }
                    e.Item.BackColor = Color.Green;
                 }

         }
```

Comment: i am using a data grid so there is no intellisense of row how can i do it in datagrid?

Comment: try "OnItemDataBound" seen on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid_members(v=VS.80).aspx